# Reg Expression Error after combining

Tags: c#, regex

> Format:
>
> TB-String1-String2-Year-NumericData1-NumericData1DigitAlways

Examples as per the above format.

TB-testdata1-testData2-2015-65789-3

This is what I have tried so for

```
    var result = Regex.Match(testData, @"\T\B-\S{2,5}\-\S{2,5}\-[\d{4}]\-\^[0-9]+$\-[\d]");

        if (result.Success)
        {
              Return match;
         Else
         {
            Return noMatch;
         }
```

It is throwing invalid argument exception.

Here is the requirement.

First two letters are always “TB”. Not Case sensitive.

Each items above are separated by “-”.

String1 --> any characters from a to z. Not case sensitive. Should be between 2 to 5 characters.

String2 --> any characters from a to z. Not case sensitive. Should be between 2 to 5 characters

Year --> always it should be 4 characters numeric data. It is year data. So it should be +ve numbers only.

NumericData1 --> Positive Numeric data only. Should be between 2 to 10 characters.

NumericData1DigitAlways --> Always 1 digit numeric data between 0 to 8 only.

I have tried each parts individually. It breaks when I concatenate the expression together.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: How this `testdata1` satisfies the second requirement ie, `Should be between 2 to 5 characters.`?

Comment: please show definition of `testData`

Comment: @GaneshaK: Please supply valid test examples. Is that valid: http://goo.gl/ogzGTJ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your conditions, your regex is not perfect. You can use

```
var result = Regex.Match(testData, @"[tT][bB]-([a-zA-Z]{2,5}-){2}\d{4}-\d{2,10}-[0-8]");
```

Explanation:

- `\S` (all characters except space) should be changed to `[a-zA-Z]` for any character between a-z and not case sensitive
- ending with `\d` should be changed to `[0-8]`
- Also, you have to remove `^ and $` for `^[0-9]+$` since they check for beginning and ending of the string

Comment: *First two letters are always “TB”. Not Case sensitive.*